# Highcharts series line and yAxis line not able to format

Tags: highcharts

I am new to using HighCharts and Javascript. Through tutorials and trial and error I have been able to get a working highcharts. The only problem now is I think I have added in some code that is making it so that I can not change the lineWidth for any of the series and cannot add a yAxis line to my chart. I have tried everything from plotOption, trying to redraw the lines and no matter what nothing on the lines change in thickness. Not even when adding hover the lines does anything happen other than the markers get bigger.

The backend works fine the html works fine. I can dynamically bring in the charts and view them and export them. Just I can not for the life of me get the lineWidth to thicken or get the yAxis to show. I event tried setting the HighChart default settings and nothing changes when it comes to lineWidth or yAxis.

I think something is overwriting the settings or my sequence is wrong. But I have not been able to figure it out. I am hopping some can  help.

Here is a picture of my HTML: [HTML of working Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjhDN.png)

Here is my code:

```
function createChart(container, title, data, hasValue2, hasValue3, isPercentage, isReversed) {
  const chartId = 'chart_' + container;

  console.log('Creating chart with ID:', chartId);

  // Call the createChartCard function to wrap the chart in a Bootstrap card
  createChartCard(title, chartId);

  // Call Highcharts.chart() after appending the chart container to the DOM
  console.log('Rendering chart:', chartId);
  
 

  // Create the Highcharts chart
  Highcharts.chart(chartId, {
    chart: {
         borderColor: '#4572A7',
         plotBorderWidth: 2,
        //plotBorderColor: '#CCCCCC',
      type: 'line',

     // width: 400, // Adjust the width as needed
   // height: 200, // Adjust the height as needed
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
},
    title: {
      text: title,
      style: {
            fontSize: '16px', // Set the font size to 10 pixels
        },
    },
    exporting: {
            enabled: true, // Enable exporting
            chartOptions: {
                chart: {
                    width: 841, // Set the chart width to fit the landscape A4 paper (841mm)
                    height: 595, // Set the chart height to fit the landscape A4 paper (595mm)
                    margin: [50, 50, 50, 50], // Set the chart margins (top, right, bottom, left)
                },
            },
        },
    legend: {
        enabled: hasValue2 || hasValue3, // Show legend if either value2 or value3 is present
        itemStyle: {
        color: 'transparent', // Make the legend text color transparent
        },
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle',
        labelFormatter: function () {
            // Hide legend entry for "Series3" when chart only has "value1" and "value2"
            if (!hasValue3 && this.name === 'Series 3') {
              return '';
            }
            return this.name; // Show other legend entries as usual
          },
        },
    xAxis: {
        //lineColor: '#FF0000',
        lineWidth: 2,
        tickLine: 0,
        tickLength: 0,
        //lineColor: 'transparent',
      type: 'datetime',
      //title: {
       // text: 'Date',
     // },
     
      labels: {
        rotation: -90,
        y: 10,
        formatter: function () {
          // Custom formatter function to display the date as "dd/m/yyyy" without leading zeros in the year
         // const date = new Date(this.value);
          //const day = date.getDate();
         // const month = date.getMonth() + 1; // Months are zero-based, so we add 1
         // const year = date.getFullYear().toString().slice(-2); // Get the last two digits of the year

          // Concatenate the formatted date components
          //return day + '/' + month + '/' + year;
          return Highcharts.dateFormat('%e %b %y', this.value);
        },
        style: {
        fontSize: '12px', // Set the font size to 10 pixels
        
    },
    
      },
      //offset: 0, // Set the offset to move the labels closer to the chart
      
    },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: isPercentage ? 'Percentage' : '',
      },
      reversed: isReversed,
      labels: {
        x: -10,
        formatter: function () {
          if (isPercentage) {
            return this.value;
          } else if (Math.round(this.value) === this.value) {
            return this.value; // Display as a whole number if it is an integer
          } else {
            return this.value.toFixed(2); // Otherwise, display with 2 decimal places
          }
           if (isReversed) {
            return -this.value; // Reverse the axis values
          } else {
            return this.value;
          }
        },
         style: {
            fontSize: '12px', // Set the font size to 10 pixels
        },
      },
       //offset: 0, // Set the offset to move the labels closer to the chart
       max: isPercentage ? 100 : null,
       //softMin: isPercentage ? 0 : 0,    // Set max to 100 if isPercentage is true
    },
    tooltip: {
      formatter: function () {
        let tooltip = Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d', this.x) + '<br>';
        if (isPercentage) {
          tooltip += 'Percentage: ' + (this.y).toFixed(2) + '<br>';
        } else if (Math.round(this.y) === this.y) {
          tooltip += 'Value: ' + this.y + '<br>';
        } else {
          tooltip += 'Value: ' + this.y.toFixed(2) + '<br>';
        }
        if (hasValue2 && this.point.y2 !== undefined) {
          if (isPercentage) {
            tooltip += 'Percentage 2: ' + (this.point.y2).toFixed(2) + '<br>';
          } else if (Math.round(this.point.y2) === this.point.y2) {
            tooltip += 'Value 2: ' + this.point.y2 + '<br>';
          } else {
            tooltip += 'Value 2: ' + this.point.y2.toFixed(2) + '<br>';
          }
        }
        if (hasValue3 && this.point.y3 !== undefined) {
          if (isPercentage) {
            tooltip += 'Percentage 3: ' + (this.point.y3).toFixed(2) + '<br>';
          } else if (Math.round(this.point.y3) === this.point.y3) {
            tooltip += 'Value 3: ' + this.point.y3 + '<br>';
          } else {
            tooltip += 'Value 3: ' + this.point.y3.toFixed(2) + '<br>';
          }
        }
        return tooltip;
      },
    },
  series: [
    // Series 1 (value1)
    {
      name: '',
      data: data.map(item => ({
        x: Date.parse(item.x),
        y: isPercentage ? item.y : parseFloat(item.y),
      })),
      color: 'black', // Default line color for Value 1
      //visible: !hasValue2 && !hasValue3, // Show only if value2 and value3 are false
      lineWidth: 4, // Increase the line width for this series
            marker: {
              enabled: true,
              radius: 4, // Increase the marker size for this series
            }, 
    },
    // Series 2 (value2)
   hasValue2
        ? {
            name: '',
            data: data.map((item, index) => ({
                x: Date.parse(item.x),
                y: item.y2 !== undefined ? (isPercentage ? item.y2 : parseFloat(item.y2)) : null,
                //color: index > 0 && item.y2 < data[index - 1].y2 ? 'red' : 'black',
            })),
            dashStyle: 'dot', // Set dash style for Value 2
            showInLegend: hasValue2,
            lineWidth: 3, // Set the line width to 3
            color: 'black', 
            marker: {
                enabled: true,
                radius: 4, // Increase the marker size for this series
                symbol: 'circle', // Increase the marker size for this series
            },
        }
        : {},
    // Series 3 (value3)
    hasValue3
      ? {
          name: '',
          data: data.map(item => ({
            x: Date.parse(item.x),
            y: item.y3 !== undefined ? (isPercentage ? item.y3 : parseFloat(item.y3)) : null,
          })),
          color: 'black', // Default line color for Value 3
          dashStyle: 'longdash', // Set dash style for Value 3
          showInLegend: hasValue3,
           lineWidth: 4, // Increase the line width for this series
            marker: {
              enabled: true,
              radius: 4, // Increase the marker size for this series
               symbol: 'circle',// Increase the marker size for this series
            }, 
        }
      : {},
  ],

    
  });
 

}

function createChartCard(title, chartId) {
  const cardHtml = `
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="card h-100 w-100">
        <div class="card-body" style="height: 100%;">
          <div id="${chartId}"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer text-muted"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  `;

  $('#chartContainer').append(cardHtml);
}

function processData(data) {
  const chartsData = {};

  data.forEach((row) => {
    const chartname = row.chartname;
     const isPercentage = Boolean(parseInt(row.ispercentage)); // Convert '0' to false, '1' to true
    const isReversed = Boolean(parseInt(row.isreversed)); // Convert '0' to false, '1' to true
    console.log(row.isreversed);
    if (!chartsData[chartname]) {
      chartsData[chartname] = {
        title: row.user + ' - ' + row.jobname + ' - ' + chartname,
        data: [],
        hasValue2: false,
        hasValue3: false,
        isPercentage: isPercentage,
        isReversed: isReversed,
      };
    }

    const x = row.wedate;
    const y = parseFloat(row.value1);

    let dataPoint = { x, y };

    if (row.value2 !== null) {
      dataPoint.y2 = parseFloat(row.value2);
      chartsData[chartname].hasValue2 = true;
    }

    if (row.value3 !== null) {
      dataPoint.y3 = parseFloat(row.value3);
      chartsData[chartname].hasValue3 = true;
    }

    chartsData[chartname].data.push(dataPoint);
    chartsData[chartname].isPercentage = isPercentage; // Set isPercentage property for the chart
    chartsData[chartname].isReversed = isReversed; // Set isReversed property for the chart
  });
  return Object.values(chartsData);
```

Comment: At first glance, I don't see any specific option that could influence on yAxis and cause this behavior. I notice you use Bootstrap, so maybe this is the thing. However to have a full view of this issue, I need to ask you to reproduce this behavior to the online editor, you can start here: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/pd3cnygu/

Comment: Thanks for looking here is my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/besadmin/svap4m93/18/                            You will need to hit the filter button and click "Clear Filter" for charts to show.

Comment: Thank you for providing the demo, I added the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the code and demo you provided, there are Highcharts styles loaded in your project and they override the chart options. In that case, you need to use CSS styling to fix that. You can read more about styles in Highcahrts in the following article: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/style-by-css

```
.highcharts-yaxis .highcharts-axis-line {
    stroke-width: 10;
    }
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/jsfiddle_demo/xg4cv5ak/

Comment: Thanks! That worked for my yAxis. I tried fiddling around with my line colors to be red or black depending on color but there still seems to be a a styling issue. I event went into the CSS and did coding to use that but the line stays black no matter what and only the marker changes color.

Comment: Try to use 'stroke', like here: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/he08gqy6/

Comment: Thank you. I handled my yAxis with your pointers. The only other thing was to handle my line color to match my marker. Still feel I have something overwriting it. Markers turn red and black but my line will not turn any color other than the default color I set. I have turned off the highcharts.css and cannot get the series line to follow the same color pattern.

Comment: In mapDataWithColor(), you change `data.color`, but this is the point's color, not line https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.data.color. You will need to modify the code and change `series.color` https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.color . Note, that it change the whole line color, if you want to change only part of line, you will need to use zones https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.line.zones